# Is there equivalent for "I am starving to death" in German?

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

For the English sentence "I am starving to death", in the meaning of "I am very hungry", (rather than of a real pathological condition), is there an equivalent in German (using the word "death")?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

German has a separate word, a more concise form for "starve to death": verhungern.

It doesn't have the word "Tod" in it, but it implies it directly. Being hungry is "hungrig" and the verb (being hungry) "hungern", but that just means starving without immediately fatal consequence.
Of course one can say "ich hungere mich zu Tode", but that's not as idiomatic and implies that starving to death being at your own hands, while "verhungern"  is due to the lack of available food by whatever causes.

Another option is to use

> sterben vor Hunger

or archaicly "des Hungers sterben" which literally means "to die because of hunger".

In a colloquial, spoken context I most often would use a wording like where the words in parenthesis might be added for emphasis or left out:

> Ich bin (grad) (voll) am Verhungern

> Ich will Euch hier (ja) nicht (ganz) verhungern lassen

Comment: Völlig unbelegt würde ich schätzen, dass "Ich sterbe vor Hunger" die verbreitetste Form ist.

Comment: Für mich klingt "Ich bin am verhungern" natürlicher :)

Comment: Can you starve not to death? I thought starve was the literal translation of verhungern which implies "to death". If starve means verhungern then starve to death is "doppelt gemoppelt" (colloquially: ein Pleonasmus) and none of the translations captures that.

Comment: "I am starving" (ich verhungere) does not imply death - it implies a process which has death at the end ;) Some people stay hungry for fasting purposes. That is still starving. Running out of food is starving - but you can just be a couple of hours or a day from the next supply point, no death coming.

Comment: @TomTom There is in German a difference between "hungern" and "verhungern". "hungern" just means to go without food and being hungry. "verhungern" implies going so hungry that it impacts your health *negatively*, ultimately fatally, thus it *does* imply death. And then there is "fasten", which is the type of purposefully and self-imposed going hungry for whatever reason (fasting).

Comment: as a native speaker without a degree in Germanistik, I would say that "sie hungert" implies that a person is lacking (sufficient) food for long periods of time, whereas "sie verhungert" implies that the lack of food is about to be fatal, like in the late stages of starvation. however "sie ist am verhungern" implies that someone is just very hungry, as in hasn't eaten for a few hours.

Comment: I think "verhungern" literally translates one-to-one to "starve", and I think the English expression "I am starving to death" is sort of a tautology since starving by itself already implies you are close to dying

Comment: The "grad voll" is nonsense: The sentence expresses a *current* situation, so "grad" ("currently") is redundant, and "voll" makes no sense, because either you *are* starving to death, or you don't; "voll" tries to maximize the statement. Nonsense as in "Mein Glas ist voll leer" or "einzigst" (heard this morning).

Comment: @TomTom Isn't "starving" close to death (as opposed to "getting hungry")? I'd say the order is like "hungry", "starving", "starved" (German: hungern, verhungern, verhungert)

Comment: As an aside, this is not the only place where German has a specific word (constructed with an appropriate prefix). which makes translations sometimes non-straightforward: *erschießen* ("shoot" alone doesn't do it, you must shoot dead), *verzweifeln*, *verbrauchen*, *verwinden*...

Comment: @U.Windl "voll" as synonym to "völlig" or "ganz" can be and is used commonly as a adjective or adverb serving to put emphasis on what it relates to. See https://www.dwds.de/wb/voll#d-1-3 . Thus your rant about its use does have little foundation and the analogy to "einzigst" is just a strawman argument. The "grad" is redundant, but language sometimes is, and here also used to put emphasis on the progress; explicitly I marked those two sentences as colloquial, spoken language.

Comment: @planetmaker Why didn't you add the more natural "Ich bin am Verhungern"?

Comment: Right, point taken. So I indicated the words  which may or may not be added for emphasis. Language is too versatile to always indicate every possibility, especially when one would also want to consider regional variations in usage.

Comment: It may be regional, but at least wikipedia agrees with me that "ich bin todhungrig" is correct German, viz https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tod-

Comment: @U.Windl no, "hungry" is "hungrig" in German. "to starve"/"starving" can mean either "hungern" or "verhungern" in German, the latter implies death. "hungern" can be more accurately translated to the uncommon "to hunger".

Answer (score 8):

The most common translation of "I'm starving to death" would be

> Ich sterbe vor Hunger

Comment: Despite knowing both words for decades, I never realised until now that Ger. *sterben* is a direct cognate of Eng. *starve*.

Comment: @PLL German has kept the original (and wider) Germanic meaning of "to become stiff" (i.e. dying for whatever reason), while English specialized it to "die from hunger". – 
So, it's actually a false friend.

Comment: In English there's a common term for a corpse, which is a "stiff."  So there might still be a connection from the German word after all.

Answer (score 6):

Another option is *Ich verhungere* or *Ich bin am Verhungern.

Comment: More "Ich bin am verhungern".

Answer (score 3):

You can use the verb "umkommen". One of its meanings is *to die*, but it can also be used to express that something is very hard to bear.

- Ich komme vor Hunger um.
- Ich komme vor Hunger fast um.
- Ich komme halb vor Hunger um.

"Umkommen" can also be combined with *Hitze* (heat), *Kälte* (cold), *Langeweile* (boredom) etc.

Answer (score 0):

"Ich habe Kohldampf." is one I've seen before. It could be out of date though but I'm not sure.

Comment: It does not imply the starving part directly.